# Trying to Get 15 Minute Intervals from MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql string to where I am trying to get a Count in 15 minute intervals from the Previous Day. Currently It does not show anything rows after 12pm. Any Ideas?

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       MINUTE(`que_timestamp`) DIV 15 AS `Peorid`,
       HOUR(`que_timestamp`) AS `Hour`
FROM `Que`
WHERE DATE (`que_timestamp`) = (CURDATE() - 1)
GROUP BY HOUR(`que_timestamp`),
         MINUTE(`que_timestamp`) DIV 15
ORDER BY `Hour` ASC
```

My `que_timestamp` is a MySQL timestamp
[image]

Comment: can you show us an example of your data ? what datatype is `que_timestamp`

Comment: Juan, I edited the post. I added a pic of the results and the que_timestamp is a MySQL Timestamp

Comment: I did some testing and your query seem to work ok. Check this [**sqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdc1e/1) maybe you could update the sqlFiddle with real data and update your question with that.